# Configurable child products without image

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, image, placeholder-image

I have one problem. I am using since a time a **new theme**, the problem is that when I select a **size** in a **configurable image**, don´t shows any image, shows the **placeholder image** of **Magento**.
The theme creator told me:
*The theme works the same as the RWD theme and it shows placeholder image since the image is not uploaded to the child product.*

Is there any possibility to `show the image of the parent product`?
You can see the example here, when you select a size no image it´s shown:
https://www.espamoto.com/casco-shark-street-drak-neon-mat-anthracite-black.html

Comment: I can´t find a solution for this